# Getting Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418 on my Gatsby production build

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am continuously getting the following error on the production build of my Gatsby app (not in develpment).

`Uncaught Error: Minified React error #418; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=418 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.`

The full error is translated into:

`Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

But the problem is that there is not a single hint about which component could be causing the issue.

My stack:

- gatsby `5.12.12`
- react-dom `18.2.0`

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing the [replaceHydrateFunction mentioned in the gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#replaceHydrateFunction) should solve this. Just try adding the following code into your `/gatsby-browser.js` file:

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";


export const replaceHydrateFunction = () => {
  return (element, container) => {
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container)
    root.render(element)
  }
}


// Replace this by your own page wrapper:
exports.wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <Layout {...props}>{element}</Layout>
}
```